# Multiple Voting in One Node

Tags: 7, rating

I couldn't come up with much constructive title, as
The Title could also be: **Separate Voting system for Fields in same Node**

In a Content Type I have 3 fields

- Mind
- Body
- Soul

all are Longtext as in the picture below.

At the moment in this content type, I am using [Plus1 Module](https://drupal.org/project/plus1) with [VotingAPI](https://drupal.org/project/votingapi) for vote, but this doesn't seem to fulfill my need.

[image]

What I am trying to acheive is to have **3** voting system, one for each field (***Mind, Body and Soul***), so, any individual can vote in any of these field.

I have tried using the [Fivestar Module](http://drupal.org/project/fivestar) and adding it as field, but it breaks my Page Layout due to JavaScript Conflict. I will post that as different question.

My question is: is there any readymade module which can help me acheive this, so, I can have Voting system for Individual Field item and store the votes in Database.

Comment: *"Is there any readymade module which can help me acheive this?"* Not that I know of. It should be fairly straight forward to implement with the Voting API module though. You just need to pass a unique `$criteria['tag']` value in the argument for each of the fields with `votingapi_set_votes()`. (and the same when retrieving the votes with `votingapi_select_votes()`).

Answer (score 0):

I've not had much luck with the plus1 module.  The 7 version is wonky.  If you're just looking for a plus 1 or like function and your fixed on the voting api then vote up/down May work for you.  You can create multiple voting fields and they are tracked separately as a field.  The widget may cause some layout issues so may I suggest using flags instead.

Why?  It's easy to add a plus1 type feature and flags can be formatted using views or flag_create_link() so you can put it every where and wrap it in any CSS div or span.  You can have as many as you'd like and it's all in the db and available to views.  You can even use rules so the system can react on a flag.  I've moved away from voting api in favour of flags.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider structuring your display differently?
1. Mind, body and soul = 3 different content types with taxonomy term "persons"
2. Use taxonomy term "persons" to link them together (person 1, person 2, etc.)
3. create 3 views, 1 for Mind, 1 for body, 1 for soul with contextual filter taxonomy term "persons" and full content display
4. create a 4th content type "full person" with the taxonomy field and 3 viewsfield and choose the person/entity in the taxonomy field (person 1 for example)
5. The views will pick the taxonomy term for each "full person" content type and display the Mind, body and soul views tagged with "persons" taxonomy and will be displayed in "full content" mode.
6. In that way you should be able to have the 3 voting system visible and usable.

I didn't tried it, it is just a guess.